# Linux Mint has weird audio issue when changing volume

Tags: ubuntu, audio, linux-mint, system-sounds, bug

Recently I installed Linux Mint 19 Cinamon. But I have a confusing problem:

When I turn the volume down to a certain level, about 80~90%, the sound just vanishes. When I turn it up, it is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Mate 20.04 I had same problem like this with my sound. Try installing pavucontrol from the snap or reinstalling it.

if installed

apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio

then install from snap store

If not working from the snap store use the command line

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

See if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried your solution. Sadly the problem remains. But I do found a clue---**When I open pavucontrol I see a little mark "base" at the volume bar. Turns out when I turn down the volume below this mark it just mute.**